# jQuery selector for a specific li

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup

```
<div id="search-query-autocomplete">
  <ul id="autocomplete-results">
    <li class="auto-li">blue</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and want to add a class to the first auto-li when the user keys down.

I have the following javascript:

```
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
 function checkKey(e){
 e = e || window.event;

 if(e.keyCode=='40')
 {
   $('#autocomplete-results li:nth-child(0)').text('not working');
   console.log('here is 40'); //code
 }
}
```

But it's not working - what do I need to change?

thx in advance

Comment: `$('#autocomplete-results .auto-li').eq(0).text('not working');`. Still leverages `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: OP might be looking for `.eq()` or `:eq()`.

Comment: @Blender the use of the psueo-selector `:eq()` cannot leverage `querySelectorAll` because it is not a native selector. We should really only offer `.eq()` to avoid the performance implications hidden in large sets of data.

Comment: `$('#autocomplete-results li').first();` also provide the first li element..

Comment: thx, just trying to get anything to work

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: I'm just letting people know that it exists. You can sacrifice a little bit of speed when first learning about how things work.

Comment: @Blender But of course my good sir. I wasn't questioning your intention what so ever. I'm just saying -- if we're going to teach people how to drive a car, we should let them know that both lanes contain traffic, but one of those lanes is probably the better one to drive in. If ya know what I mean.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Thanks, I gotcha. I'll try to mention that next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`:nth-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) pseudo-class starts at index 1 not 0

The nth child pseudo-class won't actually help in selecting the first `.auto-li`, you can use [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), [.eq(0)](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) or [`:eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to filter the selection to just the first `.auto-li`

```
$('#autocomplete-results li.auto-li').eq(0).text('working');
```

Comment: ok, thx . hmm.... so I changed to 1 and this is working (can't believe I didnt' check that) and stubbing in next text is working but an addClass('selected'). hmm... any idea what's going on?

Comment: He wants `the first auto-li`. `:nth-child(1)` will select the first li.

Comment: I think same thing? maybe this is what's causing me problem with addClass? thx for help on this

Comment: @timpone Have you tried `$('#autocomplete-results li.auto-li:first')`? Also, your code doesn't appear to have addClass in it.

Comment: yeah, I just put the text there but just next step. maybe a different question.

Comment: ok, the issue is that it is selecting but the keydown is causing this event to fire again. Probably unrelated to what I was seeing and just a simple use error

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select the first `auto-li`, your selector should actually be:

```
$('#autocomplete-results li.auto-li:first')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
 function checkKey(e){
 e = e || window.event;



 if(e.keyCode===40)
 {    
     $('#autocomplete-results li:nth-child(1)').text('not working');
   alert('here is 40'); //code
 }
}
```

**Nth-child index starts with index 1 and not with standard list index 0.**

And do not do the comparison with =='40' buth with === 40, so there is no unnecesery type conversion (buth that has nothing to do with correctnes of you're code).